# sessionStore affecting headers - Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, postgresql, express

I have this code and get this error:

https://github.com/ericx2x/notes

this error only shows when I add "store: sessionStore" to this line "router.use(session({secret: 'iloveel89', store: sessionStore, resave: true, saveUninitialized: true, logged: false, cookie: { maxAge: 7200000 }})); "

Simply adding a session store should not affect my headers.. not sure why that's the behavior I'm seeing. So far, I've tried to set `resave` to false/true and tried both psql/mysql to store my sessions. Nothing seems to get rid of this error..

> GET /api/notes 304 11.571 ms - - GET /api/password/ 304 9.699 ms - -
>   Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
>   to the client
>       at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:500:11)
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:507:3)
>       at ServerResponse.header (/home/el8le/workspace/notes/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
>       at ServerResponse.contentType (/home/el8le/workspace/notes/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:595:15)
>       at ServerResponse.send (/home/el8le/workspace/notes/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:145:14)
>       at done (/home/el8le/workspace/notes/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1004:10)
>       at Object.exports.renderFile (/home/el8le/workspace/notes/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:374:12)
>       at View.exports.__express [as engine] (/home/el8le/workspace/notes/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:417:11)
>       at View.render (/home/el8le/workspace/notes/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
>       at tryRender (/home/el8le/workspace/notes/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
>       at Function.render (/home/el8le/workspace/notes/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
>       at ServerResponse.render (/home/el8le/workspace/notes/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
>       at /home/el8le/workspace/notes/app.js:40:7
>       at Layer.handle_error (/home/el8le/workspace/notes/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
>       at trim_prefix (/home/el8le/workspace/notes/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
>       at /home/el8le/workspace/notes/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7

Comment: Can you share your /api/password/ handler?

Comment: That error tends to show up when you try to access any res.XXXX method after you've called res.send. Check your res.send calls in `routes/password.js` and see if there's anything calling res.XXXX afterwards.